# How to implement CKEditor or HTML Editor in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am building mailing system, I want html editor for message body which convert html text to plain text and show in Editor plain text and while sending mail in again convert plain text to html text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a control that is not delivered with stock Xamarin.Forms. So you need to either find a native counterpart, which I'm not sure there is, or roll your own. The nice people at Xam Consulting came up with the TEditor [here](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/TEditor).

Maybe that does what you want? Or in the least, it is a nice starting point to start working from.